# struggling with converting XMLclob data to ACORD AL3 format

Tags: xml, oracle, xslt, plsql, xsd

any one help me this below, i am struggling on converting XMLclob data to ACORD AL3 format , i am using oracle 11g with pl/sql developer tool, my XML in a table column and i need to write a package for convert XML format to AL3  format, the result AL3 insert in to same table of xml in different column   ,   if you know any think about this please post any updates or way of convert process .   advance thank you for  respond.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know nothing of AL3, but since you state your original is a CLOB containing XML data, you could try using XML based functionality.  Specifically XSLT (EXtensible Sylesheet Language) features.  You would need to create a style sheet that maps the current XML elements into your AL3 format.

As a basic outline you would select your XML data from your table into an XMLType variable.  Define another XMLType variable to contain the XLST transformation template, then apply the transform to your XML saving the results in another XMLType variable.  You can then return the XML as either an XMLType or as clob as needed:

```
declare
 l_xml xmltype;
 l_xslt xmltype;
 l_result xmltype;
begin
  l_xml := xmltype(q'[<root><value name="goober">some stuff</value></root>]');
  --select xmltype(clob_col) into l_xml from your_table where some_id=some_value;

  l_xslt := xmltype(q'[<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="no" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <!-- IdentityTransform -->
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*|/">
      <xsl:copy>
           <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>]');
  l_result := l_xml.transform(l_xslt);
  dbms_output.put_line(l_result.getclobval());
end;
/
```

The sample stylesheet here is a simple identity transform, that simply duplicates the initial XML as the result.  Not very interesting to start with, but you can add more specific templates to transform your source XML as needed.

Comment: Thank you so much ,  and to get final AL3 Format,  It's  converted basic xml right after this, is it batter to convert   XML - Acord XML - AL3.  or XML - AL3. may i know which is batter

Comment: and way of converting